# Uploading a file (server to server) with PHP using cURL

Tags: php, curl, upload, content-type

I have the following php code from my API console on RapidApi working correctly:

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://webit-computer-vision.p.rapidapi.com/describe",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "-----011000010111000001101001\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"\r\n\r\n\r\n-----011000010111000001101001--\r\n\r\n",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        "content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---011000010111000001101001",
        "x-rapidapi-host: webit-computer-vision.p.rapidapi.com",
        "x-rapidapi-key: XXXXXXXXXX"
    ],
]);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
    echo $response;
}
```

The only problem is that it also includes a file which is sent to the endpoint. How can I upload file to the given endpoint? The content-type appears to already be set correctly. I believe I just need to send the content of file in addition.

Comment: You can use CURLFile class to do it. Refer to this link: https://www.php.net/manual/en/curlfile.construct.php

Comment: thanks, I've looked at the CURLFile class. The thing I'm unsure about is how to add the file to the code above. I tried adding it to the POSTFIELDS attribute, both by leaving the Content-Disposition string as is and removing it, and then adding 'image'=> new CURLFile(...) but neither seems to work and returns: "No valid input \"image\" parameter has been provided. Check supported file types and input formats."

Answer (score 0):

for anyone wondering, I was able to get it working by modifying the header with this code:

```
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        "content-type: multipart/form-data",
        "x-rapidapi-host: webit-computer-vision.p.rapidapi.com",
        "x-rapidapi-key: VMssAjUwitmshMGT0yv1SbvOhkLVp1f3BaqjsnpKZ8t9yLcbxs"
    ]
```

and then had to change the following to get the image file to POST properly:

```
$fields = [
    'image' => new \CurlFile("images/2021_04_01_Ied8W_Ex0P-meVoActjCQ.jpg", 'image/jpeg', 'filename.jpg')
];
...
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $fields,
...
```

started working pretty quickly after that =)